# How to check using a script if project is opened in XCode?

Tags: xcode, git, bash

I'd like to introduce build number feature for my iPhone project and increase it automatically with every commit to my git repo. I plan to do it using Apple's `agvtool`, which recommends that project is not opened in XCode at the time

So my questions are:
1) So far I know that I need to make an executable script from `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample`. How to do the scripting to check if certain project is opened in XCode?

2) `pre-commit.sh` will be executed upon calling `git commit` with no args, so whenever someone will commit with `-a` option, I won't have my build number updated. Is there any way to workaround this?

Cheers

Comment: What OS are you developing on?

Comment: I don't know if this will work on Mac, but on linux something like `ps ux | grep -ce 'xco[d]e'` will tell you whether or not xcode is running. I suspect that Mac will also have `ps` and `grep`.

Comment: @Michael: `ps ux | grep -ce 'Xcode'` does the thing, but as you write tells only whether Xcode is running and I'd need information whether MyProject.xcodeproj is opened by it (or opened/used by any other process). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I can't remember what it is, but there's a command that will list all open files. Google can probably find it for you. Piping that through grep might do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode supports AppleScript. I tested this with Xcode 4.2 but I think it ought to work in earlier releases.

First, write a script file, `isXcodeProjectOpen.scpt`:

```
-- Returns 1 if a project in the given directory is open, otherwise 0
on run argv
    set _path to first item of argv
    tell application "Xcode"
        repeat with _p in projects
            if project directory of _p is _path then
                return 1
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    return 0
end run
```

Then you can run that from the shell like this:

```
ISOPEN=`osascript isXcodeProjectOpen.scpt /path/containing/project`
if [ -z $ISOPEN ]; then
   # all clear
else
   # not safe to run agvtool!
fi
```

Comment: This is a great answer, the scripts do exactly what I needed back then. I just changed if condition to `$ISOPEN -eq "0"`. Thank you, Benzado!

Answer (score 1):

I know neither of Xcode or agvtool but reading your question I have the impression you want to increment your build number each time you make a commit. It looks strange to me as committing to git is not related to the actual build.

You'd better add a hook in your build system than in git.

Comment: Disagree. I have seen many software packages where the version number is something like 1.2.3.4567, where 4567 corresponds to the SVN revision number. Makes debugging easier - if you have to trace an issue, you know exactly which version of the code to be looking at. The way this is often done is as VCS commit hook which updates a properties file, which is then built into the version screen or whatever.

Comment: @gabuzo: Micheal correctly explained my reasons behind introducing build numbers. It may look weird or even stupid to make something like SVN's revision numbers under Git, but for testing between official releases it's simply more convenient than Git's 40 byte long commit id. Anyway, I didn't find any better solution for this.

Comment: @Michael. Sure SVN revision number is handy and more user friendly than git's SHA1. Regardless of how the build number is generated how this number is going to be included in the delivery?

Comment: Help -> About or command --version or whatever equivalent will display the version number as (e.g.) 1.2.7865 (major.minor.svnrevision)

Comment: @Michael I meant how this revision number is going to get into the code, not how it is displayed in the application.

Comment: @gabuzo: You wrote that you don't use XCode/agvtool, so here's small explanation: http://www.innerexception.com/2008/10/iphone-app-version-and-build-numbers.html. Therefore I just need a script in git hook telling me that my project is not opened in XCode and based on that increment my build number on every commit.